# Enable WireMock Rule in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I am trying to enable response-template for Wiremock. The [documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/) states that the following code needs to be added:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wm = new WireMockRule(options()
    .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(false))
);
```

However, this @Rule annotation is for JUnit and currently, I am not running wiremock in junit tests. So, is there a way to enable WireMockRule in the application scope?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add the extensions while initializing WireMockServer with WireMockConfiguration.

```
WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(new WireMockConfiguration().port(PORT).extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(false)));
```